# Need NSNotification to work through the whole app in iOS

Tags: ios, nsnotification

I need to check whether your wifi status has changed throughout the whole app. I am using Reachability to check whether the wifi status is on.

I have set up an observer like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
```

The problem is I need to add this addObserver and removeObserver to all viewcontrollers and the reachabilityChanged function to all.

Is there a better method then adding NSNotification whether I check the wifi status throughout the whole app?

Need some guidance and suggestions on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

make a `super viewController` called `rootViewController` to `subClass` the `UIViewController` and in the `init` to init the `Notification` and in the `dealloc` to remove the `Notification`

And then all your `viewController` should `subClass` the `rootViewController` . It just `OOP`

like :

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];

    }
    return self;
}
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // you can do nothing , it should be override.
}
```

And when you creat your viewController , you should subclass the `RootViewController`

```
@interface YourViewController : RootViewController

- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // if your super class method do some things you should call [super reachabilityChanged:notification]
    // do your thing.
}

@end
```

In the `implementation` you should achieve the `reachabilityChanged:` method

Comment: In the implementation you should achieve the reachabilityChanged: method -> meaning in rootviewcontroller right?

Comment: @lakesh no , it is YourViewController

Comment: Good idea! But it is not a perfect solution, think about if you want to inherit from a class other than directly inheriting from UIViewController (UITableViewController for example). It may be better to add a notification observer in appdelegate. Then go through all viewcontrollers in the viewcontroller stack, and send a message to the viewcontrollers which can respond the method.

Comment: @onevcat Yes,such as UITableViewController it will not work , and you can creat a RootTableViewController and so on , but I think it not very perfect , and we can avoid our controller inherent UITableViewController , but I think it also not very perfect. I have a best way and I have done it before , it is to make a UIViewController category , and then use runtime to dynamic add a subclass(just to remove the notifaction) , when UIViewController invocate dealloc , the dynamic subclass will auto remove notifaction. It is not a word and my English is poor . maybe you donot understand what I said

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, If i keep all my neccessary functionality in my super class, i still need to have this: - (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     [super reachabilityChanged:notification]
    // do your thing.
} Am i right?

Comment: @lakesh if you keep all your neccessary functionality in your super class , you do not need to have that method in the child class.But if you want to do different thing for different viewController , you should keep that method in the child class and override that method , and if you want use the super class method you should in that method call [super xxxxx] or you do not need call [super xxxx]

Comment: @GuoLuchuan I understand what you mean. It could be done by swizzling or some other runtime tech. But you have to be very careful about the selector in case of a unrecognized selector error.

Comment: @lakesh it is like init method , if you do not have property to set up , you can not keep init , and you can use init , because the super class has write the init

Comment: @lakesh There is no need to do so. If the subclass can not respond to the message, it will be redirected to the super class by default.

Comment: @onevcat very cool , you understand what I said . I have edit my answer , the super class has achieve the selector , and the child class only should override it or not

Comment: so if I do not have the method in the child class, it will still automatically get  called?

Comment: @lakesh if you do not have the method in the child class , it will call the method in the super class(RootViewController)

Answer (score 1):

I would make a `UIViewController` category and expose methods that subscribe and unsubscribe from the notification at hand, and also provide a default implementation of what needs to happen in the case of reachability being lost. The advantage of a category over inserting a new class into the inheritance hierarchy is that you can have subclasses of framework view controllers, e.g. `UITableViewController`s, take advantage of the methods.

Example category and view controller code follows:

```
@interface UIViewController (CVReachability)

- (void)cvObserveReachability;
- (void)cvUnobserveReachability;

- (void)cvHandleReachabilityNotification:(NSNotification *)notification;

@end

@implementation UIViewController (CVReachability)

- (void)cvObserveReachability
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(cvHandleReachabilityNotification:)
                                                 name:REACHABILITY_NOTIFICATION_NAME
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)cvUnobserveReachability
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:REACHABILITY_NOTIFICATION_NAME
                                                  object:nil];
}

- (void)cvHandleReachabilityNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    /*************************************************************
     * Anything that happens in this method should be appropriate for
     * every UIViewController in your application.
     ************************************************************/
    NSLog(@"Reachability notification handler: %@", notification);
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

...

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self cvObserveReachability];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self cvUnobserveReachability];
}

- (void)cvHandleReachabilityNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [super cvHandleReachabilityNotification:notification];

    /*****************************************************************
     * Do whatever is appropriate response for this view controller's 
     * area of responsibility. Perhaps show an alert...
     *****************************************************************/
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Problem" message:@"Maybe your internet is down?" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

...

@end
```

Comment: @lakesh Thank you! I often use this any time I would be otherwise inserting another "abstract" class below `UIViewController`, and it usually pays off.

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea, except to use to pull up functionality into superclasses you didn't create.

Comment: this means that I need to add [self cvObserveReachability]; and [self cvUnobserveReachability]; to all viewcontrollers?